# Apache 2.4 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so', libcurl.4.dylib

Tags: php, apache, curl, macos-sierra

I'm running *macOS 10.12*, *Apache 2.4*, and *PHP 7.2.7*

When I add the line: LoadModule php5_module `libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
to my *httpd.conf* I get the following errors.

```
httpd not running, trying to start
```

> **Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so'
>   (tried:
>   /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/curl.so
>   (dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/curl.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/curl.so
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: curl.so requires version 9.0.0
>   or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0),
>   /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/curl.so.so
>   (dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/curl.so.so,
>   9): image not found)) in **Unknown** on line **0**
>
> **Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so'
>   (tried:
>   /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so
>   (dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: http.so requires version 9.0.0
>   or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0),
>   /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so.so
>   (dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718//usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/http.so.so,
>   9): image not found)) in **Unknown** on line **0**

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 92:   719 Segmentation fault: 11  $HTTPD "$@"
```

I updated curl with brew and it shows:

```
/usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
```

I still get the same error.

Why is the error showing libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0 when it is version 9.0.0? Is it pointing to an older version of the file? They both show this location `/usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works.

> $ brew install httpd php72

I followed the instructions to setup the httpd.conf file and the php.ini file and Apache starts fine now.

Answer (score 0):

it basically reads:

> requires version 9.0.0 or later, but *.dylib provides version 7.0.0

this means, you have to install these libraries at version `9.0.0`, instead of version `7.0.0`.

it's also strange that `dlopen()` complains about filename suffix `.so.so`

Comment: This library ( /usr/local/php5/lib/libcurl.4.dylib ) says it is version 9. If I need a newer version, where do I get it? Google is not helpful in that regard. I already ran 
    $ brew install curl